# javascript dropdown list choice dependent on previous selection

Tags: javascript

I have had to go back to the drawing board as my previous js did not work with my new database structure.

I can not figure out how to use JavaScript to populate a dropdown list dependent on the previous dropdown list selections

I have 5 drop down lists in total with the options selected dependent on the previous choices selected.

The issue I have is the dropdown boxes being created do not send their value when using GET on form submission and I am unaware for how to define that value.

Please can someone give me advice on creating these dropdown lists? Google searches are bringing up ideas but not sufficient for anything with more than 2 drop down lists.

thanks

html

```
<select id="product" name="products" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,'faulttype')">
    <option value="">select</option>

    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
    <option value="test3">test3</option>
    <option value="test4">test4</option>

</select>

    Fault Type:

    <select id="faulttype" name="faulttypes" onchange="configureDropDownLists2(this,'faulttype2')">
        <option>{blank}</option>
    </select>

    Fault Type2:

    <select id="faulttype2" name="faulttypes2" onchange="configureDropDownLists3(this,'faulttype3')">
        <option>{blank}</option>
    </select>

    Fault Type3:

    <select id="faulttype3" name="faulttypes3">
        <option>{blank}</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </fieldset>
```

js

```
var test1 = new Array('test5', 'test6', 'test7');
var test2 = new Array('test8', 'test9', 'test10');
var test3 = new Array('test11', 'test12', 'test13');
var test4 = new Array('test14', 'test15', 'test16');

switch (product.value) {

    case 'test1':
        document.getElementById(faulttype).options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < test1.length; i++) {
            createOption(document.getElementById(faulttype), test1[i], test1[i]);
        }
        break;

    case 'test2':
        document.getElementById(faulttype).options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < test2.length; i++) {
            createOption(document.getElementById(faulttype), test2[i], test2[i]);
        }

        break;
    case 'test3':
        document.getElementById(faulttype).options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < test3.length; i++) {
            createOption(document.getElementById(faulttype), test3[i], test3[i]);
        }
        break;

    case 'test4':
        document.getElementById(faulttype).options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < test4.length; i++) {
            createOption(document.getElementById(faulttype), test4[i], test4[i]);
        }
        function configureDropDownLists2(faulttype, faulttype2) {
            var test5 = new Array('test15', 'test14');
            var test6 = new Array('test16', 'test17');

            switch (faulttype.value) {
                case 'test5':
                    document.getElementById(faulttype2).options.length = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < test5.length; i++) {
                        createOption1(document.getElementById(faulttype2), test5[i], test5[i]);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'test6':
                    document.getElementById(faulttype2).options.length = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < test6.length; i++) {
                        createOption1(document.getElementById(faulttype2), test6[i], test6[i]);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            function createOption1(ddl, text, value) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                var ddl = document.getElementById('faulttype2');

                opt.value = value;
                opt.text = text;
                ddl.options.add(opt);
            }
```

Comment: Are you leveraging web services here? Typically your first dropdown calls a web service to be populated. Then you bind its onchange event to a handler that populates the second drop down. Then you bind the onchange event of the second dropdown to a handler that populates the third. Make sense?

Comment: i am still learning js , i will look up iteration. i will past the code i have been using that works but because of database change to relational i now need the values to match the ID numbers in my data base but i dont know how to set values correctly in the created option

Comment: i have put in the previous code i was using to create my drop down list and it worked. but now i am using $_GET in my database query i need the values to match the ID's from the relevant tables